# No animation when pushing view controllers in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, animation, uikit

I have a storyboard set up with a `UITabBarController` which contains a `UINavigationController` for each tab. For one of the `UINavigationControllers` there are no transition animations when pushing or presenting a view controller.

There are, at least, two different cases when this happens

**1.** I have a storyboard segue set up to push the child view controller. The segue triggers when selecting a cell in a table view. The "Animates"-box is checked.

[image: The Attributes of the segue]

Attempting to programatically push the child view controller yields the same result.

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextController, animated: true)
```

**2.** There is also no animation when attempting to modally present another view controller from the root view controller of the navigation controller.

```
modalViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.flipHorizontal
self.present(modalViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If I present the `modalViewController` from another view controller the transition is animated which leads me to believe that there is something wrong in the root view controller that is presenting.

Is there a way to disable animations on a `UIViewController` that I might accidentally have triggered? I have checked and verified that there are no `UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)`

Comment: Can you pack and upload your demo project?

Comment: The terms view and view controller are **NOT** interchangeable. I edited your question title to say "...when pushing view **controllers**..."

Comment: @OwenZhao I am unable to reproduce this in a demo project and cannot upload my real project

Comment: @DuncanC Thanks. Obvously I am not pushing views.

Comment: It's just about impossible for us to tell what's going on from the outside. You're seeing some strange, non-standard behavior, and since you can't either reproduce it in a demo project or share your real project, I'm not sure how we can help. Have you tried replacing the source view controller with an ordinary UIViewController as a test? You might need to do that, and then start customizing the source view controller with the traits of your view controller a few at a time, and testing repeatedly, watching for the behavior to come back.

Comment: @DuncanC I understand that. I was hoping that someone had run into a similar case and could point me in the right direction. However, I have found what was causing the issue and will add an answer. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my overridden `viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)` of the parent view controller I had some code that reset the state of a custom view. The reset did in turn disable actions via `CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)`, thus disabling the transition animations.

Moving the reset to `viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool)` resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. That makes your question thread useful to anyone else who has the same problem. Now that you describe it it makes sense. Searching for calls to `setDisableActions` or `removeAnimations` in your code would have been a good suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Use `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(` instead of `self.present(`

You set up animation in UINavigationController. But you called the function `self.present(` which is provided by UIViewController. UIViewController of course cannot provide the animation.

Comment: I guess I was not clear enough that there are two different examples. One push using segue and one programatically modally presenting another view controller. I have updated the question to clarify. Also programatically pushing the view controller does have the same result.